# Twitter-like routes in ASP.NET MVC 2 application

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-2, routes

I'd like to have routes set up as follows:

`xyz/` maps to one action method with no parameters, but `xyz/{username}` maps to a different action (in the same controller or not, doesn't matter) that takes an argument called username of type string. Here are my routes so far:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Me",
    "Profile",
    new { controller = "Profile", action = "Me" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Profile",
    "Profile/{username}",
    new { controller = "Profile", action = "Index" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Currently, if I navigate to `/Profile/someuser`, the Index action in the Profile controller is hit as expected. But if I navigate to `/Profile/` or `/Profile`, I get 404.

**What gives?**

Comment: Wow, sorry, I accidentally had the Me() method set to private. That took way too long to spot. I hate bugs like that, you pull your hair out for hours and it turns out to be drop-dead trivial. I actually suspected it would be something dumb like that but I was at wit's end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works fine for me. I suppose you do not have a `Me` action method in your `Profile` controller?

I tried with the following routes:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Me",
    "Profile",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Me" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Profile",
    "Profile/{username}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
);
```

With the `Index` and `Me` action methods defined like this :

```
public ActionResult Index(string username) {
   ViewData["Message"] = username;
   return View();
}

public ActionResult Me() {
   ViewData["Message"] = "this is me!";
   return View( "Index" );
}
```

I used the default `Home/Index` view.

Comment: +1 for the non-repro. Commenting the `Me()` results in a 404. You're likely right on the lack of a  `Me()` in the controller.